# How to select ListViewItem with left mouse button only?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

How can i prevent the right click from selecting an item in my listview both in click and double click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this code, I think it should do the work. You need to set some `bool` variable to indicate that the right mouse has been clicked in your `MouseDown`, then `Clear` selected items, if SelectedIndexChanged event handler fired because of the right click and then reset the indicator on `MouseUp` event. Check the code:

```
bool rightClicked = false;
private void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        rightClicked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        rightClicked = false;
    }
}
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rightClicked)
    {
        listView1.SelectedItems.Clear();
    }

}

private void listView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    rightClicked = false;
}
```

**EDIT:** This is the best I could do, it preserves the selection but flickers. the solution could be implemented using some custom drawing of the items but that requires too much time. I leave that to you.

```
bool rightClicked = false;
int [] lviListIndex = null;
private void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
      {
            rightClicked = true;
            lviListIndex = new int[listView1.SelectedItems.Count];
            listView1.SelectedIndices.CopyTo(lviListIndex, 0);
      }
      else
      {
            rightClicked = false;
      }
}
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (rightClicked)
      {
            listView1.SelectedIndices.Clear();   
      }
}

private void listView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
      if (rightClicked)
      {
            listView1.SelectedIndexChanged -= new System.EventHandler(listView1_SelectedIndexChanged);
            if (lviListIndex != null)
            {
                 foreach (int index in lviListIndex)
                 {
                      listView1.SelectedIndices.Add(index);
                 }
            }
            lviListIndex = null;
            listView1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(listView1_SelectedIndexChanged);
      }
      rightClicked = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nikola but wont this cancel any selection of left mouse button?

Comment: I think we can replace this code before changing the selection and cancel the selection if rightclicked=false

Comment: I don't understand what exactly do you mean. Can you be more specific? Have you tried the code? It worked for me.

Comment: If i have a listview with four items then i selected the first items using left click then clicked on the second item with the right mouse button the selection disappears .
I want to keep the first item selected as long as i didn't select any other item with the left button

Comment: @SaraSaeed Ok, I get it, well, that will take some time. I'll post the answer in few minutes

Comment: @SaraSaeed Check the answer now, I had to do some work so I couldn't do it faster.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass the listview and add this override:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            const int WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205;
            const int WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204;

            if ((m.Msg != WM_RBUTTONDOWN) && (m.Msg != WM_RBUTTONUP))
            {
                base.WndProc(ref m);
            }
        }
```

This works by ignoring messages from the right button of the mouse.

Answer (score -1):

you can check like this  `if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)`

Comment: Thanks Ravindra but in which event do u mean?

Comment: @SaraSaeed:in mouse up event